# Integrate PayPal via php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, paypal

I am trying to integrate `paypal` into a pet adoption website that I am building. However I had a basic code working, and when I built around it, it stopped forwarding to the `paypal` website to make the payment.

This is the page that is supposed to start and finish the charge and then save the information to the database.

the code i have to make the sale :

```
$product = $dogname;
$price = $deposit;
$shipping = 0.00;

$total = $price + $shipping;

$payer = new Payer();
$payer ->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

$item = new Item();
$item -> setName($product)
    ->setCurrency('USD')
    ->setQuantity(1)
    ->setPrice($price);
$itemList = new ItemList();
$itemList ->setItems([$item]);

$details = new Details();
$details ->setShipping($shipping)
    ->setSubtotal($price);

$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency('USD')
    ->setTotal($total)
    ->setDetails($details);

$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)
    ->setItemList($itemlist)
    ->setDescription("Deposit for ". $dogname);
$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(SITE_URL . "/adoption.php?success=TRUE")
    ->setCancelUrl(SITE_URL . "/adoption.php?success=FALSE");

$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale')
    ->setPayer($payer)
    ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
    ->setTransactions([$transaction]);
try{
    $payment ->create($paypal);
} catch(Exception $e){
    die($e);
}
$approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();
?>
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){
    window.location = "<?php echo $approvalUrl; ?>";
}, 100);
</script>
<?php
}
```

And then to process the sale on my end

```
$paymentId = $_GET['paymentId'];
$payerId = $_GET['PayerID'];

$payment = Payment::get($paymentId, $paypal);
$execute = new PaymentExecution();
$execute->setPayerId($payerId);
try{
    $result = $payment->execute($execute, $paypal);
?>
<script>
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location = "/adoption.php?payment=success";
}, 100);
</script>
<?php

}catch(Exception $e){
    $data = json_decode($e->getData());
    var_dump($data->message);
}

}else{
    die();
}
    echo "Payment Made";
```

thanks in advance for the help, I've been looking on `youtube` and `stackoverflow` but cant seem to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: the description of your problem / error / difficulty is too vague and you also potentially seem to be describing several different problems simultaneously. Question needs clarifying.

Comment: It would be 600% more readable when you properly format the code

Comment: Not sure about security tho, you don't seem to implement best practice. You shouldn't put too much in GET parameters. They will end up in log files of proxies etc which is against data privacy.

Comment: DanFromGermany, I removed the indentions because this website kept saying my code wasn't in code blocks... So that's why it's not formated. 

However my 2 issues is that it's not forwarding anymore. And I'm not sure how to add in a processing fee...

Comment: I went through and formated the code to make it easier to read and I also adjusted my issue in the top. Thanks

Comment: "not forwarding anymore" isn't really an adequate description of the problem. What debugging have you done? What errors / unexpected behaviour are you experiencing, precisely? Try and narrow down the problem.

Comment: Like I said. Theres no error codes, it's not putting out anything the page just stops when you submit the form.

Comment: in that case add some debugging output so you can see what happens and where it goes. You need to learn to trace the flow of your program.

Comment: Well that's the issue. I've had multiple websites and been able to track multiple issues. This is the first program I've made that does any transactions. And I'm just not able to get any response out of them...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my error.

When I adjusted the web page to make it auto fill the form from the database. The form wasn't sending one of the field items and was leaving it blank on the POST request. So the page just stopped and killed itself...